# Real time traffic sign recognition in android

Tags: android, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to develop a mobile app for traffic sign recognition and i want it to be in real-time. I'm trying only to detect circles signs and to find out what sign is in order to notify the driver. I want to know what is the best method I should use. For now I've tried using java and opencv to find the circles in an image (using HoughCircles) but is not quite what I've expected - a lot of signs aren't identified. Then I tried to use opencv  for training it to learn the signs - to obtain an xml trained classifier, but it takes too long and to be functionally I need a really large amount of data. I don't know what to do ... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can share some of them with us(input and output of your app)?

Comment: What framerate are you running at. You might get better results on a lower framerate, while still being (roughly) real-time.

Answer (score 1):

I found this work with some research: https://www.academia.edu/4950526/Traffic_Sign_Recognition_system_on_Android_devices